# 16.04 touchscreen laptop, closed lid and when open a whole bunch of apps have started and done random things

Tags: suspend, laptop, touchscreen

So, I have a touchscreen laptop and when I close my lid and open it some time later, a bunch of apps have launched and it seems like random mouseclicks have happened all over the place.

in 16.04, how can I set the mouse, touchpad, and touchscreen to do nothing when the lid is closed? It is set to suspend when close lid.
Let me know if any more information is required, and let me know how to get this information.

System info.
HP envy 17-t
Intel® Core™ i7-4510U CPU @ 2.00GHz × 4 
GeForce GTX 850M/PCIe/SSE2
64-bit Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please choose suspend in "when lid closed" option is power settings.
settings -> power.

If your issue still persist then you can execute below commands:

```
xinput list
```

the above command will list all your device names.

To disable your touch screen panel. Run

```
xinput set-prop <touch-device-name> "Device Enabled" 0
```

To enable your touch screen panel. Run

```
xinput set-prop <touch-device-name> "Device Enabled" 1
```

You can setup these commands in your /etc/acpi/handler.sh
So that your acpi events could handle this.

Comment: I did chose that option. I mentioned it above.
Do you think this function may not be working? If so, are there any steps you can recommend?
I have tried setting it to "do nothing" and then restarting... then back to "suspend" and then restarting. That didnt do anything.